# What is the best way to propagate event to few component instance in Vue Js?

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2

I need to implement folowing behavior->
I have the list with simple elements (just text). In elements i put the button "edit", that open edit element form on same place.
I have "add" button on top of list, that open same form.

I'd like to: when user click on "add" or "edit" another opened forms close. Also forms closed after sending request to server..

Sorry for my English! )

It looks like that:

List and add element form:

```
<template>
<el-row>
    <el-col :span="24">
        <el-button type="text" @click="show_add_form = true">Добавить</el-button>
        <edit-dict-element-form 
            v-bind:dict="dictName" 
            v-if="show_add_form"
            v-on:closeAddForm="show_add_form = false">
        </edit-dict-element-form>
    </el-col>
    <el-col :span="24"
        v-for="(element, index) in dict"
        v-bind:key="element.id">
        <dict-element 
            v-bind:element="element"
            v-bind:index="index"
            v-bind:dict="dictName">
        </dict-element>
    </el-col>
</el-row>
```

Element component:

```
<template>
  <div>
    <el-card v-if="!show_edit_form">
       {{element.name}}
       <el-button class="edit-button" type="text" @click="show_edit_form = true">Изменить</el-button>
    </el-card>
    <edit-dict-element-form 
        v-bind:dict="dict" 
        v-bind:edit_element="element"
        v-if="show_edit_form"
        v-on:closeAddForm="show_edit_form = false">
    </edit-dict-element-form>
  </div>
</template>
```

Add\Edit element form:

```
<template>
    <el-card>
        <el-form :rules="rules" :model="element" label-position="top" ref="AddDictElement">
            <el-form-item label="Введите значение" prop="name">
                <el-input v-model="element.name"></el-input>
            </el-form-item>
        </el-form>
       <el-button type="danger" @click="$emit('closeAddForm')">Закрыть</el-button>
       <el-button type="success" @click="addDictElement">Сохранить</el-button>
    </el-card>
</template>
```

I'd like to only one add\edit form was opened at same time.

Comment: Could you show what you've already tried so far, a workable fiddle?

Comment: post some samples

Answer (score 0):

You could use an 'event bus' system for communicating between components (non parent-child communication).

```
var bus = new Vue()

// in component A's method
bus.$emit('id-selected', 1)

// in component B's created hook
bus.$on('id-selected', function (id) {
    // ...
})
```

Please see:
https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components.html#Non-Parent-Child-Communication

Comment: I have one Vue instance (work via single-file components). In this logic this.$on and this.$emit have to work everywhere.. But they don't. ))